# How to add specific string to existing string in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

My column pattern as below.

```
<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:1-<Not-Static-String> 

<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:7-<Not-Static-String>
```

etc...

I would like to insert 0 before 1 like this;

```
<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:01-<Not-Static-String> 

<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:<3CHARS>:07-<Not-Static-String>
```

I have tried to use CONCAT but didn't write correct SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
   SET columnName = substr(columnName, 1, 12) || '0' || substr(columnName, 13);
```